# Problem installing Epson Perfection V370 scanner drivers

Tags: scanner

I'm trying to install drivers for my Epson Perfection V370.

I've downloaded the driver from the Epson site to my Desktop.
Opened a terminal which is by default pointed at the Desktop.
Ran (as noted from the read me within the driver package).

```
tar xaf iscan-perfection-v370-bundle-2.30.4.x64.deb.tar.gz \
   cd iscan-perfection-v370-bundle-2.30.4.x64.deb \
   ./install.sh
```

This is copied from the terminal,

```
~/Desktop $ tar xaf iscan-perfection-v370-bundle-2.30.4.x64.deb.tar.gz
~/Desktop $    cd iscan-perfection-v370-bundle-2.30.4.x64.deb
~/Desktop/iscan-perfection-v370-bundle-2.30.4.x64.deb $    ./install.sh
[sudo] password for graham: 
Hit:1 http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal InRelease
Hit:2 http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-updates InRelease
Ign:3 http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu disco-updates InRelease
Hit:4 http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-backports InRelease
Err:5 http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu disco-updates Release
  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.88.142 80]
Hit:6 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-security InRelease
Reading package lists... Done                    E: The repository 'http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu disco-updates Release' does not have a Release file.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
~/Desktop/iscan-perfection-v370-bundle-2.30.4.x64.deb $
```

No idea what it means or if it installed correctly, when i run 'document scanner' app i get a 'no scanner available' message and i need to install drivers?

Do i need to do something more, if so what?

Comment: What version of Ubuntu are you using? It appears that you have a very strange sources.list

Answer (score 1):

I just freshly installed an Ubuntu 20.04 system, installed the driver for the V370, and it is working fine.

My steps were:

- Install sane sane-utils libsane-common xsane
- Install the Epson driver using `./install.sh`
- Copy the `79-udev-epson.rules` (the same from 18.04) to `/etc/udev/rules.d/`

Now everything is working fine.

Answer (score 0):

As I understand, you are trying to install it on Ubuntu 20.04. The driver has is release date 08-22-2019, so it's not designed for Focal Fossa. Should work OK with 18.04.

Perhaps it will work with [SANE](http://www.sane-project.org/) (Scanner Access Now Easy)  but not sure. I have the same problem with an Epson L365, because of this I'm downgrading my system.

Answer (score 0):

Ended up using a different scanner, a scanner built in to a Epson sx415, the drivers installed easily and both scanner and printer works well.

Thanks for the input Claudio